# React setState dynamically - how to setState property and value from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm trying to create a single handler to update the state.
For now i have many handlers - one for every component.
What i'm trying to do is create switch function and one handler to handle all state changes.

Here's the switch function, for now it has only one case:

```
function liftingUpStateHandler(type, e, state){
    switch(type){
        case 'imageClickHandler':
            let array = state.bottomGalleryItems;
            const index = array.findIndex((object) => object.cardId === e);
            window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
            return  ['items', [state.bottomGalleryItems[index]]]
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
export default liftingUpStateHandler;
```

And i'm trying to create one handler in main app.js file :

```
  stateHandler = (type, e) =>{
    const result = liftingUpStateHandler(type, e);
    this.setState({result[1]: result[2]})
  }
```

If this would work i can just add cases to liftingUpStateHandler and update state with only one handler.

(one to rule them all) :)

What i'm dealing now is a lot of functions like this:

```
loaderScreenHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({loader: e})
  }

  modalCloseHandler = () =>{
    this.setState({noexifdatafilenames: []})
  }

  markerFlyerTo = (e) => {
    const index = (markerFlyerHandler(e, this.state));
    this.setState({ activeCard: index });
  }

  deleteItem = (e) => {
    const result = (deleteItemHandler(e, this.state));
    this.setState({ items: result[0]});
    this.setState({ activeCard: 0 });
  };

  changeActiveCardRight = () => {
    const result = (changeActiveCardRightHandler(this.state, 'right'));
    this.setState({ activeCard: result });
  }

  changeActiveCardLeft = () => {
    const result = (changeActiveCardRightHandler(this.state));
    this.setState({ activeCard: result});
  }

  closeHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ fullScreen: false})
  }
```

... But i'm getting an error:

```
Failed to compile

./src/App.js
SyntaxError: C:\Users\Sławek\Desktop\dev\geolocapp\src\App.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (63:25)

  61 |   stateHandler = (type, e) =>{
  62 |     const result = liftingUpStateHandler(type, e);
> 63 |     this.setState({result[1]: result[2]})
     |                          ^
  64 |   }
  65 |
  66 |
```

Is this even possible?
Or i need to take different approach like REDUX ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.setState({result[1]: result[2]})
```

To do a [computed object property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015), you need to use square brackets around the key:

```
this.setState({ [result[1]]: result[2] })
```

Also, i think you meant to use `result[0]` and `result[1]`, so it would be:

```
this.setState({ [result[0]]: result[1] })
```

Comment: Great! Thank you.  I didn't knew what to search for.